# How to make a method like markAsRead which is available for notifications in laravel

Tags: laravel

[Laravel notifications](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/notifications#marking-notifications-as-read) has a method which you can mark unread messages as read. how can we build a similar method for our collection to update specific column on a collection.

Example:

```
//to make sold column set as true
$products = Product::where('any thing')->get()->markAsSold()
```

I realized something like this is possible using `each` attribute on collection.

```
$products->each->markAsSold();
```

`markAsSold` is a method in Product Model

Comment: What did you try to make this work? Did you look at the source code of Laravel notifications to read how it was done?

Comment: So `markAsSold` is highly likely to be a method in your `Product` class, it's just that simple.